# How do I animate text repeatedly and without waiting?

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to make some text appear and do it's animation, then fade out. I got that part working, but I want it to be repeatable and without having to wait for the animation to finish. For example I am testing this in my code with a button click, and I want the text to do it's animation every time I hit the button without waiting for the animation to finish. When it's done I should have the text animated on screen multiple times. And remember, I don't want to interrupt the current animations.

Code:

```
<p id="test" hidden="true">Test</p>
<button id="random">Random</button>



$(function() {
$('#random').click(function(){
    minusHealth();
});

function minusHealth() {
var health = parseInt($('#health').text());

        health = isNaN(health) ? 0 : health - 1;
        $("#test").removeAttr("hidden");
        $("#test").animate({top:'250px'}, 900);
        $("#test").fadeOut(400);

    $('#health').text(health);

}
});
```

Comment: _"with a button click, and I want the text to do it's animation every time I hit the button without waiting for the animation to finish"_ , _"I don't want to interrupt the current animations"_  ? At first glance , first sentence appear to indicate _interrupting_ currently running animation ; second sentence _not interrupting_ currently running animation ? If possible , can clarify requirement ? Thanks

Comment: Basically I want to have the animation to work every time I hit the button, and I don't want it to interrupt the current animations. So I want the word "test" to be animating every time I push the button. It won't work without a different approach since it animates the text and it can only be used once without interrupting the animation.

Comment: guest271314 If you look at cookie clicker for example, when you click the cookie the text is animated. I need something similar to that.

Comment: Not certain what "cookie clicker" is ? See post. Thanks

Comment: i don't see any element with id health. You're fading out an element in `400ms`, then what's the point in animating the `top` value for `900ms`? anyway it won't be visible after `400ms`.

Comment: The question is unclear and the code doesn't make sense. Can you explain what is the animation you're trying to achieve..? i.e: what exactly should happen to `#test` when you keep on clicking the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) for `.fadeOut()`

```js
$(function() {
$('#random').click(function(){
    minusHealth();
});

function minusHealth() {
var health = parseInt($('#health').text());

        health = isNaN(health) ? 0 : health - 1;
        $("#test").removeAttr("hidden");
        $("#test").animate({top:'250px'}, 900);
        $("#test").fadeToggle(400);

    $('#health').text(health);

}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test" hidden="true">Test</p>
<button id="random">Random</button>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I am looking for. It's really hard to describe what I want it to do. I have seen many other developers use it for games and other things. Cookie clicker does pretty much what I want.